# How to use com.apple in Java 1.8?

Tags: java, macos, gradle

When compiling a Java Mac application using `Gradle` I get errors like this:

```
error: package com.apple.eawt does not exist
```

But `com.apple.eawt` is present in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar`

If I copy `rt.jar` to some other location and add it to the class path e.g. by

```
compile fileTree(dir: '/Users/XXX', include: 'rt.jar')
```

then it magically works! Is there some trick to persuade Java to use platform dependent stuff in `rt.jar`?

Comment: Clearly, that's not where Java is running from. If `java -version` tells you it is running 8u60 then there must be a jre1.8.0_60 that it's using which lacks the `com.apple` classes.

Comment: I have to agree with @DavidConrad.  It sounds like it's loading a Java 1.6 or prior version which has `com.apple.eawt` in a different location.  You can tell this for sure by setting `sourceCompatibility = 1.8` in your `build.gradle` and seeing if that makes it bomb.

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution:

```
compileJava {
    options.compilerArgs << "-XDignore.symbol.file=true"
    options.fork = true
    options.forkOptions.executable = 'javac'
}
```

Comment: This works but in Gradle 3.5 it now generates the following error: `The executable property on ForkOptions has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use javaHome instead.`

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a bit old but I thought it might be useful to someone. With gradle 3.5 the forkOptions.executable is deprecated. The javaHome property must be used instead:

```
compileJava {
  options.fork = true
  options.forkOptions.javaHome = new File("${System.properties.'java.home'}")
  options.compilerArgs << "-XDignore.symbol.file=true"
}
```

See the JavaDoc of the ForkOptions class https://docs.gradle.org/3.5.1/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/compile/ForkOptions.html